# How do you extract a column from a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, extract

Does anybody know how to extract a column from a multi-dimensional array in Python?

Answer (score 289):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])

>>> A
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8]])

>>> A[:,2] # returns the third columm
array([3, 7])
```

See also: "numpy.arange" and "reshape" to allocate memory

Example: (Allocating a array with shaping of matrix (3x4))

```
nrows = 3
ncols = 4
my_array = numpy.arange(nrows*ncols, dtype='double')
my_array = my_array.reshape(nrows, ncols)
```

Comment: Took me 2 hours to discover [:,2] guess this feature not in official literature on slicing?

Comment: What does the comma mean?

Comment: @Phil `[row, col]`. the comma separates.

Comment: How can this answer have so many upvotes? OP never said it's a numpy array

Comment: for extract 2 columns: A[:,[1,3]] for example extract second and fourth column

Comment: @sziraqui Good thing there are non-numpy solutions then. Numpy is incredibly useful when working with matrices in Python, and pretty much _the_ standard, and this is just an example of it (performance is another reason).

Comment: Excellent! It has a very good performance for extracting columns!

Comment: Atleast tell it's numpy, agree that it's efficient but without library is better

Answer (score 258):

Could it be that you're using a [NumPy array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays)? Python has the [array](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html) module, but that does not support multi-dimensional arrays. Normal Python lists are single-dimensional too.

However, if you have a simple two-dimensional list like this:

```
A = [[1,2,3,4],
     [5,6,7,8]]
```

then you can extract a column like this:

```
def column(matrix, i):
    return [row[i] for row in matrix]
```

Extracting the second column (index 1):

```
>>> column(A, 1)
[2, 6]
```

Or alternatively, simply:

```
>>> [row[1] for row in A]
[2, 6]
```

Comment: This should be the top answer. It answers the asked question while pointing to an alternative in NumPy.

Answer (score 110):

If you have an array like

```
a = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
```

Then you extract the first column like that:

```
[row[0] for row in a]
```

So the result looks like this:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 54):

check it out!

```
a = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
a2 = zip(*a)
a2[0]
```

it is the same thing as above except somehow it is neater
the zip does the work but requires single arrays as arguments, the *a syntax unpacks the multidimensional array into single array arguments

Comment: What is above? Remember that the answers are not always sorted the same way.

Comment: This is clean, but might not be the most efficient if performance is a concern, since it is transposing the entire matrix.

Comment: FYI, this works in python 2, but in python 3 you'll get generator object, which ofcourse isn't subscriptable.

Comment: @RishabhAgrahari Anyway to do this zip in Py3?

Comment: @WarpDriveEnterprises yup, you'll have to convert the generator object to list and then do the subscripting. example: `a2 = zip(*a); a2 = list(a2); a2[0]`

Comment: Or simply `list(zip(*a))[0]`

Comment: For python 3, do `next(zip(*a))` to get the first column in the form of a tuple. To get the same result in the form of a list, I think it's faster to use list comprehension instead.

Answer (score 18):

```
>>> x = arange(20).reshape(4,5)
>>> x array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])
```

if you want the second column you can use

```
>>> x[:, 1]
array([ 1,  6, 11, 16])
```

Comment: This is using numpy?

Comment: I can't find any documentation for `arange()` in Python3 outside of numpy. Anyone?

Comment: i think it is tensorflow, @KevinWMatthews

Answer (score 17):

```
array = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]

col1 = [val[1] for val in array]
col2 = [val[2] for val in array]
col3 = [val[3] for val in array]
col4 = [val[4] for val in array]
print(col1)
print(col2)
print(col3)
print(col4)

Output:
[1, 5, 9, 13]
[2, 6, 10, 14]
[3, 7, 11, 15]
[4, 8, 12, 16]
```

Comment: 16 likes, and nobody realize that `val[4]` is out of range... Python starts the index at 0.

Answer (score 17):

If you have a two-dimensional array in Python (not numpy), you can extract all the columns like so,

```
data = [
['a', 1, 2], 
['b', 3, 4], 
['c', 5, 6]
]

columns = list(zip(*data))

print("column[0] = {}".format(columns[0]))
print("column[1] = {}".format(columns[1]))
print("column[2] = {}".format(columns[2]))
```

Executing this code will yield,

```
>>> print("column[0] = {}".format(columns[0]))
column[0] = ('a', 'b', 'c')

>>> print("column[1] = {}".format(columns[1]))
column[1] = (1, 3, 5)

>>> print("column[2] = {}".format(columns[2]))
column[2] = (2, 4, 6)
```

Answer (score 16):

```
def get_col(arr, col):
    return map(lambda x : x[col], arr)

a = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]

print get_col(a, 3)
```

map function in Python is another way to go.

Answer (score 12):

```
[matrix[i][column] for i in range(len(matrix))]
```

Answer (score 9):

The itemgetter operator can help too, if you like map-reduce style python, rather than list comprehensions, for a little variety!

```
# tested in 2.4
from operator import itemgetter
def column(matrix,i):
    f = itemgetter(i)
    return map(f,matrix)

M = [range(x,x+5) for x in range(10)]
assert column(M,1) == range(1,11)
```

Comment: use itertools.imap for large data

Comment: The itemgetter approach ran about 50x faster than the list comprehension approach for my use case.

Python 2.7.2, use case was lots of iterations on a matrix with a few hundred rows and columns.

Answer (score 7):

You can use this as well:

```
values = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
values[...,0] # first column
#[1,4]
```

Note: This is not working for built-in array and not aligned (e.g. np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7]]) )

Answer (score 7):

let's say we have `n X m` matrix(`n` rows and `m` columns) say 5 rows and 4 columns

```
matrix = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16],[17,18,19,20]]
```

To extract the columns in python, we can use list comprehension like this

```
[ [row[i] for row in matrix] for in range(4) ]
```

You can replace 4 by whatever number of columns your matrix has.
The result is

`[ [1,5,9,13,17],[2,10,14,18],[3,7,11,15,19],[4,8,12,16,20] ]`

Comment: Does this create an entirely new list?

Answer (score 6):

I think you want to extract a column from an array such as an array below

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]])
```

Now if you want to get the third column in the format

```
D=array[[3],
[7],
[11]]
```

Then you need to first make the array a matrix

```
B=np.asmatrix(A)
C=B[:,2]
D=asarray(C)
```

And now you can do element wise calculations much like you would do in excel.

Comment: While this helped me a lot, I think the answer can be much shorter:
1. A = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]])
2. A[:, 1]  >> array([ 2,  6, 10])

Answer (score 5):

One more way using matrices

```
>>> from numpy import matrix
>>> a = [ [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9] ]
>>> matrix(a).transpose()[1].getA()[0]
array([2, 5, 8])
>>> matrix(a).transpose()[0].getA()[0]
array([1, 4, 7])
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use transpose(), then you can get the columns as easy as you get rows

```
matrix=np.array(originalMatrix).transpose()
print matrix[NumberOfColumns]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to grab more than just one column just use slice:

```
 a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]])
    print(a[:, [1, 2]])
[[2 3]
[5 6]
[8 9]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Well a 'bit' late ...

In case performance matters and your data is shaped rectangular, you might also store it in one dimension and access the columns by regular slicing e.g. ...

```
A = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]     #< assume this 4x2-matrix
B = reduce( operator.add, A ) #< get it one-dimensional

def column1d( matrix, dimX, colIdx ):
  return matrix[colIdx::dimX]

def row1d( matrix, dimX, rowIdx ):
  return matrix[rowIdx:rowIdx+dimX] 

>>> column1d( B, 4, 1 )
[2, 6]
>>> row1d( B, 4, 1 )
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The neat thing is this is really fast. **However**, negative indexes don't work here! So you can't access the last column or row by index -1.

If you need negative indexing you can tune the accessor-functions a bit, e.g.

```
def column1d( matrix, dimX, colIdx ):
  return matrix[colIdx % dimX::dimX]

def row1d( matrix, dimX, dimY, rowIdx ):
  rowIdx = (rowIdx % dimY) * dimX
  return matrix[rowIdx:rowIdx+dimX]
```

Comment: I checked this method and the cost of retrieving column is way cheaper than nested for loops. However, reducing a 2d matrix to 1d is expensive if the matrix is large, say 1000*1000.

Answer (score 2):

Despite using `zip(*iterable)` to transpose a nested list, you can also use the following if the nested lists vary in length:

```
map(None, *[(1,2,3,), (4,5,), (6,)])
```

results in:

```
[(1, 4, 6), (2, 5, None), (3, None, None)]
```

The first column is thus:

```
map(None, *[(1,2,3,), (4,5,), (6,)])[0]
#>(1, 4, 6)
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the next hint:
having the matrix named `matrix_a` and use `column_number`, for example:

```
import numpy as np
matrix_a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]])
column_number=2

# you can get the row from transposed matrix - it will be a column:
col=matrix_a.transpose()[column_number]
```

Answer (score 0):

All columns from a matrix into a new list:

```
N = len(matrix) 
column_list = [ [matrix[row][column] for row in range(N)] for column in range(N) ]
```