# Converting some columns of a matrix from float to int

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix `tempsyntheticGroup2` with 6 columns. I want to change the value of columns `(0,1,2,3,5)` from `float` to `int`. This is my code:

```
tempsyntheticGroup2=tempsyntheticGroup2[:,[0,1,2,3,5]].astype(int)
```

but it doesn't work properly and I loose the other columns.

Comment: You can use a list to be a index of other list, but not this way. I think that there is a mistake in your code. Can you share the entire matrix? Are you sure that list values are float? I am asking because the list `[0,1,2,3,5]` are integers.

Comment: What is the `dtype` of `tempsyntheticGroup2`; also its `shape`?

Comment: While it is technically possible for a numpy array to contain heterogeneously typed elements if its dtype is `np.object`, in practice this is almost never a good idea for performance reasons. It might make sense to use a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) or a [pandas `DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html), although perhaps the most straightforward option would be to store the columns  that need to have different dtypes in separate arrays and address them by a common row index.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can have a numpy array with some element that are ints, and some that are floats (there is only one possible `dtype` per array). But if you just want to round to lower integer (while keeping all elements as floats) you can do this:

```
# define dummy example matrix
t = np.random.rand(3,4) + np.arange(12).reshape((3,4))

array([[  0.68266426,   1.4115732 ,   2.3014562 ,   3.5173022 ],
       [  4.52399807,   5.35321628,   6.95888015,   7.17438118],
       [  8.97272076,   9.51710983,  10.94962065,  11.00586511]])



# round some columns to lower int
t[:,[0,2]] = np.floor(t[:,[0,2]])
# or
t[:,[0,2]] = t[:,[0,2]].astype(int)

array([[  0.        ,   1.4115732 ,   2.        ,   3.5173022 ],
       [  4.        ,   5.35321628,   6.        ,   7.17438118],
       [  8.        ,   9.51710983,  10.        ,  11.00586511]])
```

otherwise you probably need to split your original array into 2 different arrays, with one containing the column that stay floats, the other containing the column that become ints.

```
t_int =  t[:,[0,2]].astype(int)

array([[ 0,  2],
       [ 4,  6],
       [ 8, 10]])


t_float = t[:,[1,3]]

array([[  1.4115732 ,   3.5173022 ],
       [  5.35321628,   7.17438118],
       [  9.51710983,  11.00586511]])
```

Note that you'll have to change your indexing accordingly to access your elements...

Comment: Hello @Julien, can you check if type(t[0,0]) returns numpy.int64? Because in my experiment, type() returns numpy.float32 in Python 3.10.13. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use wrong syntax to get column data.

read this article.

[How do you extract a column from a multi-dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903853/how-to-extract-column-from-a-multi-dimentional-array)

Comment: Please include content in your answer, not links, because links break and then the answers become unusable.