# how to extract a column from a matrix in python without using any package

Tags: python, matrix

I want to find a sum of a column in a matrix without using any package.

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
```

If I want to extract a row I can write `a[i]` for ith row, but how to extract a particular column?

Comment: my favorite way from the dup: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13518274/6045800

Answer (score 0):

So you can get the ith row with `a[i]` and you can get the nth value from row i with `a[i][n]` now if you want the column as a whole you will want something like this:

```
def getColumn(data,col):
    return [k[col] for k in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access any element :

```
def sumColumn(m, column):
    sum = 0
    for row in range(len(m)):
        sum += m[row][column]
    return sum

column = 1
print("The sum for column number", column, "is", sumColumn(matrix, column))
```